# What's more readable naming conventions for lookup tables?

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions

We always name lookup tables  - such as Countries,Cities,Regions ... etc  - as below :
`EntityName_LK` OR `LK_EntityName` ( Countries_LK OR LK_Countries )
But I ask if any one have more better naming conversions for lookup tables ?

**Edit**:
We think to make postfix or prefix to solve like a conflict :
if we have `User` tables and lookup table for `UserTypes` (ID-Name) and we have a relation many to many between `User` & `UserTypes` that make us a table which we can name it like `Types_For_User` that may make confusion between `UserTypes` &  `Types_For_User` So we like to make lookup table `UserTypes` to be like `UserTypesLK` to be obvious to all

Comment: Why do you even have to use a special prefix/postfix for a lookup table? How do you distinguish a lookup table from a "regular" data table?? I would just use clear names, e.g. `Country` (or `Countries`) and be done with it...

Comment: we make the prefix OR postfix to distinguish between regular table and lookup ones

Comment: in a previous project we used `LU_` as the prefix. E.g `dbo.LU_Glossary`.

Comment: @RPM1984 , from your work is it better to use prefix OR postfix ?

Comment: id go with prefix, for sorting and instant readability.

Comment: I agree with marc_s. IMO, you should try to understand why you are designating some tables as "lookup" and others not. Each table should represent an entity unto itself. If you use a prefix or suffix, what happens when the entity "grows" beyond being a "lookup"? Changing a table name is a major pain in the butt.

Comment: @Thomas, please read what i write in Edit to understand why i need to distinguish lookup table with prefix or postfix instead of direct/clear names

Comment: @Space Cracker - Still don't agree. Just use the "Member" suffix on the junction table. So you have Users, UserTypes, UserTypeMembers

Comment: @Thomas, 'Member' is a way to do that but i don't see it readable and efficient, you can replace it with Users_UserTypes

Comment: @Space Cracker - First, I not a fan of underscores in object names. They're a  pain to type. Second, "efficient" depends greatly on one's perspective. A table named "UserTypes_Lookup" that has to be changed at some later date because it is isn't really a "lookup" (whatever that means) or must keep that name even though it isn't a "lookup", is far less efficient than finding a name that represents the relationship. What is a user "type"? Is that a role? Why not use Roles, Users, UserRoles (or RoleMembership).

Comment: @Space Cracker - If you use "User_UserTypes", what happens if you later need to add another foreign key?

Comment: @Thomas,i agree with you that's will be a problem if we add new columns that make this table not a lookup and changing name isn't good and keeping it as is make its name not express content

Comment: @Thomas, if i have 'Users' , 'UserTypes' so you mean that the third will be like 'UserTypesMemebership' ???

Comment: @Space Cracker - Or just UserTypeMembers. Remember you are seeking a noun for table names. UserTypeMembers would have UserTypeId and UserId as foreign keys. Another approach is to use the word "role". So, Users, Roles, RoleMembers where RoleMembers would have UserId and RoleId as foreign keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before you decide you need the "lookup" moniker, you should try to understand why you are designating some tables as "lookups" and not others. Each table should represent an entity unto itself.

What happens when a table that was designated as a "lookup" grows in scope and is no longer considered a "lookup"? You are either left with changing the table name which can be onerous or leaving it as is and having to explain to everyone that a given table isn't really a "lookup".

A common scenario mentioned in the comments related to a junction table. For example, suppose a User can have multiple "Types" which are expressed in a junction table with two foreign keys. Should that table be called `User_UserTypes`? To this scenario, I would first say that I prefer to use the suffix `Member` on the junction table. So we would have `Users`, `UserTypes`, `UserTypeMembers`. Secondly, the word "type" in this context is quite generic. Does a `UserType` really mean a Role? The term you use can make all the difference. If `UserTypes` are really Roles, then our table names become `Users`, `Roles`, `RoleMembers` which seems quite clear.

Comment: How about when you have a State table, and its ID is meaningful. Say in my application I want a feature to behave a certain when it's california? If (State.Id == (int)LookUpState.Ids.California)

Comment: That is yet another reason to not use a generic "lookup" table. A dedicated table of provinces would be better. Technically, State abbreviations are a form of a code, so I'd probably name that PK "Code" so you'd have "Province.Code = 'CA'". Typically, I associate the column name "Id" with surrogate keys rather than known codes. The word "Lookup" adds no value to your naming here.

Answer (score 7):

Here are two concerns for whether to use a prefix or suffix.

1. In a sorted list of tables, do you want the LK tables to be together or do you want all tables pertaining to EntityName to appear together
2. When programming in environments with auto-complete, are you likely to want to type "LK" to get the list of tables or the beginning of EntityName?

I think there are arguments for either, but I would choose to start with EntityName.

Comment: for auto complete environment we can make LK as postfix to avoid writing it all time

Answer (score 6):

Every table can become a lookup table.
Consider that a person is a lookup in an Invoice table.
So in my opinion, tables should just be named the (singular) entity name, e.g. Person, Invoice.

What you do want is a standard for the column names and constraints, such as

```
FK_Invoice_Person (in table invoice, link to person)
PersonID or Person_ID (column in table invoice, linking to entity Person)
```

At the end of the day, it is all up to personal preference (if you can get away with dictating it) or team standards.

*updated*

If you have lookups that pertain only to entities, like Invoice_Terms which is a lookup from a list of 4 scenarios, then you could name it as Invoice_LK_Terms which would make it appear by name grouped under Invoice.  Another way is to have a single lookup table for simple single-value lookups, separated by the function (table+column) it is for, e.g.

```
Lookups
Table | Column | Value
```

Comment: I mean tables that almost have (ID-Name) always are made as lookup only

Comment: Updated for single-table-related lookups

Comment: you agree 'LK_Table' but i don't understand what u mean by simple-value lookups

Comment: If you have a list of date intervals (day, week, fortnight, month, biannual, annual, biennial), it is a simple lookup list. Let's say you have another list - payment type: Cash, EFT, Cheque, Trade.  that's another simple list. You could make a table for each, or I normally just dump them into a single lookup table with a key defining what type of lookup they are.

Comment: but this will make some difficult if you want to use in reporting or to make physical relation between table, also we can face a problem if we want to change this data from just lookup to add more columns ... it's a better way to use your way for unchanged values

Answer (score 1):

There is only one type of table and I don't believe there is any good reason for calling some tables "lookup" tables. Use a naming convention that works equally for every table.

Answer (score -1):

One area where table naming conventions can help is data migration between environments. We often have to move data in lookup tables (which constrain values which may appear in other tables) along with schema changes, as these allowed value lists change. Currently we don't name lookup tables differently, but we are considering it to prevent the migration guy asking "which tables are lookup tables again?" every time.

Comment: Lookup tables are indeed valid, specialized table types:

"A look-up table deals with attributes and their values, not entities"
from Selko via https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/